# Using thread for something different when waiting for WebService call

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, tomcat

I have a very simple Spring application which publishes a REST service(1). The service is calling another web service(2) to retrieve data. The call to retrieve the data takes 2-3 seconds.

I now run into the problem that there will be lots of people calling the Spring web service(1) but the response time increases dramatically since every call has to wait for the second call to be finished.

My current understanding is, that every call which is not directly handled will land in a queue. I have four CPUs which 2 threads each, 8 simultaneous working threads.

Is there any way to free up the threads when they are waiting for the service call(2) to be finished?

Comment: You're tagging this "tomcat": Is this a spring application running on tomcat, or a spring application elsewhere, calling webservices on tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to handle this is to have more threads than you have CPUs, and rely on the thread scheduler to switch between threads.

For example ... assuming there are 2 cores and 3 or more threads

1. Server accepts request R1 and starts processing it on thread T1 running on core C1.
2. Server accepts request R2 and starts processing it on thread T2 running on core C2.
3. Server accepts request R3 and dispatches it to thread T3.  T3 can't run at the moment (no free cores) so it waits to be scheduled.
4. T1 reaches the point where is sends the request to the other service.  The request is sent, and T1 blocks waiting for the reply.  This frees core C1.
5. T3 is scheduled to run on C1 and processing of request R3 gets underway.

Basically, the blocking, unblocking and scheduling is all handled behind the scenes by Java and the OS.  And if you are using Servlets, the container will handle the worker thread pool and the dispatching of requests to threads.

This works fine for up to a hundred or so<sup>1</sup> threads; i.e. a hundred or so requests being handled simultaneously.  Beyond that the overheads of too many threads (e.g. thread stack memory) and too much scheduling / context switching can impact on throughput.  At that point you need to look into a framework that supports asynchronous processing<sup>2</sup> where threads switch between requests rather than blocking.

---

<sup>1 - The point at which having too many threads will impact on performance will depend on a variety of factors that are difficult to predict.</sup>

<sup>2 - The Servlet 3.0 spec supports asynchronous request handling, so if you need this, look for a web container that supports Servlet 3.0; e.g. Tomcat 7 or later.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Will this also apply when calling methods from external libraries instead of calling a webservice e.g. WebServiceTemplate?

Comment: Maybe.  It depends on what the external library does.  If is simply computing without doing any I/O and without synchronizing with other threads, then T1 (in the example) may never block.  In that case, T3 typically has to wait until T1 is finished before it can be scheduled.